# Are the quasinormal modes of a black hole actually Fourier modes?

Tags: black-holes, klein-gordon-equation, linear-systems

The quasisnormal modes of charged black holes coupled to a charged massive scalar field is such that the equation of motion for the scalar field is the Klein-Gordon equation

$$[\nabla^{\nu}-iqA^{\nu}]^{2}\Psi= 0.$$

See Hawking and Ellis for the derivation of this equation.

See also equation 1 of [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1006.4439.pdf) paper.

Is this equation a linear differential equation?

Which features of the equation determine the linearity of the equation?

Comment: 1. That's not the standard Klein-Gordon equation. 2. What exactly about the [definition of a linear differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation), specifically *" They equate 0 to a polynomial that is linear in the value and various derivatives of a variable; its linearity means that each term in the polynomial has degree either 0 or 1."* is unclear to you that you cannot check whether this equation fulfills that definition or not?

Comment: @ACuriousMind : I'd even go simpler than that.  An equation $O(f) = 0$ is linear if, for the operator $O$, and two solutions $O(f_{1}) = 0$ and $O(f_{2}) = 0$, and any two constants $a,b$, you have $O(a\,f_{1} +b\, f_{2}) = 0$, which is obviously also super-easy to check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, we may cast the differential equation in the form,

$$L\psi = 0$$

for the differential operator,

$$L = (\nabla^\mu - iq A^\mu)^2.$$

We may expand this operator as,

$$(\nabla^\mu - iq A^\mu)(\nabla_\mu - iq A_\mu) = \nabla^2 -iq \nabla^\mu A_\mu - iq A^\mu \nabla_\mu - q^2 A^2 = \nabla^2 - q^2 A^2 - iq(\nabla^\mu A_\mu + \mathcal L_A).$$

where we have replaced $A^\mu\nabla_\mu$ with the Lie derivative, with the assumption the operator is only applied to a scalar function. You can now check the linearity explicitly; clearly $q^2 A^2$ is obviously a linear operator since it is multiplication by a scalar function, as well as $\nabla^2$ the Laplacian.

We also have $\mathcal L_A(c_1 f_1 + c_2 f_2) = c_1\mathcal L_A f_1 + c_2 \mathcal L_A f_2$. With the final remaining term, we have that, $$\nabla^\mu (A_\mu f) = \partial^\mu (A_\mu f) - \Gamma^{\sigma \mu}_\mu A_\sigma f$$

which is equivalent to differentiation and multiplications by functions, which once again is a linear operation on any scalar function. Thus the operator overall is a linear operator.